# Correct syntax for foreign key constraint for multiple foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

As per this example what is the correct syntax for a `foreign key constraint` for multiple foreign keys that all reference the same `primary key` from the referenced table?

```
ALTER TABLE team
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_team_players
FOREIGN KEY (player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4, player_5, player_6, player_7, player_8) 
REFERENCES player (player_id)
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to do them separately:

```
ALTER TABLE team
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_team_players1
FOREIGN KEY (player_1) 
REFERENCES player (player_id)

ALTER TABLE team
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_team_players2
FOREIGN KEY (player_2) 
REFERENCES player (player_id)

...
ALTER TABLE team
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_team_players8
FOREIGN KEY (player_8) 
REFERENCES player (player_id)
```

you can also do it in one instruction as below

```
ALTER TABLE team
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_team_players1 FOREIGN KEY (player_1) REFERENCES player (player_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_team_players2 FOREIGN KEY (player_2) REFERENCES player (player_id),
...  
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_team_players8 FOREIGN KEY (player_8) REFERENCES player (player_id),
```

I recommend you to change table structure to keep players not in columns but in other table in rows.

Comment: is there not a way to write a custom FK constraint so all the foreign keys can be referenced in one hit?

Comment: @PaulStevens Unfortunately - know. You can change your table structure to keep those 8 players in other table

Comment: how about a custom function that considers all of the foreign keys and returns a boolean - false if any of the foreign keys do not exist - sorry, clutching at straws maybe........

Comment: @PaulStevens You create `FK` to avoid preparing this kind of functions/procedures